# Реал-тайм поиск на ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticcloud, php, elasticsearch

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, как сделать поиск в режиме реального времени с ElasticSearch? Например, чтобы показать результаты строки на веб-странице после ввода клавиатуры. (так же, как автозаполнение Jquery).

Я знаю, что есть некоторые библиотеки, но я не понимаю клиентскую часть, это должен быть AJAX запрос на PHP или URL?

Какой простой способ сделать это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На странице должен быть *javascript* который будет выполнять *AJAX* запрос, это может свой скрипт или часть компонента. Серверная часть должна отвечать за поиск и выдачу ответа этому скрипту.

Делать *elasticsearch* доступным из интернета небезопасно. Я бы сделал *php* скрипт с вызовом библиотеки для работы с *elascticsearch* например [Elasticsearch-PHP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html) которая бы формировала запрос к *elasticsearch* и возвращала *JSON* в ответ.

Как один и примеров реализации обратил бы внимание на эту [статью](https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams).

Answer (score 1):

В ElasticSearch для этого есть специально Suggesters API: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html